# How to handle UUIDs in a merge or cherry-pick?

Tags: git

i tried out some concepts for a git-workflow for about some hours, but want to ask some more experienced users about that.

**The situation**
We have 3 projects/repos **'main-prj'**, **'second-prj'** and **'third-prj'**
Those repos are 95% identical. They only differe in some names and Uuids.
Our changes and features we are only adding in the **main-prj** will need to be merged or picked into the other repos.

**The problem**
Lets say i add a new Uuid (myUuid = '2e9618f0-e529-4d22-810b-3dfd62f5c4bd') those will later be added to the other repos. But its important, that those Uuids are not duplicated.

Is There any possibility to provoke a conflict at this part, so that i can change the ID while merging later?

Is this even best practise to try that?

Comment: that sounds like an enviroment variable. there are solutions with `.env` file and gitignore :)

Comment: " We have 3 projects/repos 'main-prj', 'second-prj' and 'third-prj' Those repos are 95% identical. They only differe in some names and Uuids. Our changes and features we are only adding in the main-prj will need to be merged or picked into the other repos."  Then why do you have 3 repos?

Comment: Thats why i asked "Is this even best practise to try that?"
Maybe you know a better solution @erik258